# Laravel - makeVisible doesn't make hidden attribute visible

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, lumen

I have the following code:

```
$model = new coretable;
    log::info($model->all());
    $model = $model->makeVisible('id_coretable');
    log::info($model->all());
```

In my lumen log, I get the following result:

```
[2020-02-26 10:14:19] local.INFO: [{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_1"},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_2"},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_3"},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_4"},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_5"}]  
[2020-02-26 10:14:19] local.INFO: [{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_1"},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_2"},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_3"},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_4"},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_5"}]
```

I would expect the `"id_coretable"` attribute to be present in the second output from `log::info()`, but it isnt.
Why is that?
Here is the model of coretable:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CoreTable extends Model
{

    /**
   * The table associated with the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
   protected $table = 'coretable';


  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
    'Internal_key'
  ];

  protected $hidden = [
    'id_coretable',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
  ];

  protected $primaryKey = 'id_coretable';



  /**
   * Many-To-Many relationship with User-Model.
   */
  public function extensiontable_itc()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\extensiontable_itc', 'coretable_id');
  }

  public function extensiontable_sysops()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\extensiontable_sysops', 'coretable_id');
  }

  public function inaccessibletable()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\inaccessibletable', 'coretable_id');
  }
}
```

I have no clue why makeVisible() doesnt have any effect on the effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial model you created does not have any influence on the models received from the `all()` function. This is a collection of new models with the initial `$hidden` array.

To change what values are shown, you will have to call `makeVisible` on the collection you receive:

```
$model = new coretable;
log::info($model->all());
log::info($model->all()->makeVisible('id_coretable'));
```

It is also recommended to call the query functions staticaly, this way you don't need to create an initial model:

```
log::info(coretable::all()->makeVisible('id_coretable'));
```